# How to access a private field of the super class of the super class with reflection in Java?

Tags: java, reflection

In one API I am using I have an *Abstract Class* (**Class A**) that has a *private field* (**A.privateField**).
  **Class B** *extends Class A* within the API.
I need to extend Class B with my implementation of it, **Class C**, but I need privateField of class A. 
I should use reflection: How can I access a private field of a super super class?

```
Class A
    - privateField
Class B extends A
Class C extends B
    + method use A.privateField
```

Comment: I think the private field of Class A may be protected instead of private, so you can access it from Class C without reflection.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The fact that you need to do this points to a flawed design.

However, it can be done as follows:

```
class A
{
  private int privateField = 3;
}

class B extends A
{}

class C extends B
{
   void m() throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException
   {
      Field f = getClass().getSuperclass().getSuperclass().getDeclaredField("privateField");
      f.setAccessible(true); // enables access to private variables
      System.out.println(f.get(this));
   }
}
```

Call with:

```
new C().m();
```

One way to do the **'walking up the class hierarchy'** that Andrzej Doyle was talking about is as follows:

```
Class c = getClass();
Field f = null;
while (f == null && c != null) // stop when we got field or reached top of class hierarchy
{
   try
   {
     f = c.getDeclaredField("privateField");
   }
   catch (NoSuchFieldException e)
   {
     // only get super-class when we couldn't find field
     c = c.getSuperclass();
   }
}
if (f == null) // walked to the top of class hierarchy without finding field
{
   System.out.println("No such field found!");
}
else
{
   f.setAccessible(true);
   System.out.println(f.get(this));
}
```

Comment: +1 Also, if the field is simply on "a superclass" without knowing exactly which, you can walk up the class hierarchy, checking each class in turn to see if it contains the field (until you hit `Object`).

Comment: Thank you! I am starting using reflection and this is a really useful start!

Comment: Yep, that's the gist of what I meant (comments aren't really suitable for code).  However the `while (true)` means the loop can only ever end with an exception (and will eventually throw an NPE if the field is not found).  `while (c != null)` would be a better condition

Comment: And as a more minor point, the example above throws exceptions in the "usual" case of the field not being there, which is quite expensive.  If this were to be used in a library or in performance-critical code, it may be better to call `c.getDeclaredFields` instead, and then call `getName()` on the `Field` objects returned until one is found with the given name (or the array is exhausted).  It's more complex to write but much faster to run, and so is worth bearing in mind.

Comment: @AndrzejDoyle Changed check to `c != null` and improved error checking.

Comment: @AndrzejDoyle You are right about using `getDeclaredFields`. `getDeclaredField` searches through all fields regardless, so I don't suppose it has any advantage other than simplicity (which is often enough). I must say I'm not particularly fond of either method. It would've been nice if there was a `getDeclaredField` that used `Map` and returned `null` rather than throwing an exception, or a similar `hasDeclaredField`.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way, if you're using springframework.

```java
// Attempt to find a field on the supplied Class with the supplied name. Searches all superclasses up to Object.
Field field = ReflectionUtils.findField(C.class, "privateField");
```