# NoSuchField Exception in reflection

Tags: java, reflection

i wrote a code to get  value of a attribute of a object using reflection but it gives nosuchfield exception.The class which contain id field is

```
public class PartialSettBank {

// empty constructor
public PartialSettBank() {
}


protected Integer id;

protected String bankCode;

protected String bankName;

protected String description;

protected Integer isDeleted = 0;

protected Integer isPosted = 1;

protected Integer active;

protected LocalDateTime created;

protected String createdBy;

protected LocalDateTime updated;

protected String updatedBy;

------getter setter()
}
```

I want to access id field using reflection

```
Field id = object.getClass().getDeclaredField("id");
id.setAccessible(true);
```

this object is from class 'PartialSettBank'.object contains id field.I checked it.why it is giving such error i have no idea.

Comment: You should probably provide more code...

Comment: Show the code that has the field called `id`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access a private field of the super class of the super class with reflection in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18830701/how-to-access-a-private-field-of-the-super-class-of-the-super-class-with-reflect)

Comment: Are you sure 'object' is an object of the class 'PartialSettBank' (and not its subclass's object)?

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to:

```
Field id = PartialSettBank.class.getDeclaredField("id");
id.setAccessible(true);
```

Then it doesn't matter whether the object you are working with is a direct instance of `PartialSettBank` or an instance of a subclass. You will still be able to use the `Field` object with an instance of a subclass or a direct instance of `PartialSettBank` itself.